# changing rmarkdown "table of contents" default title

Tags: r, r-markdown, docx, tableofcontents

I am using RMarkdown to write my MSc thesis, in a language different than English. The thesis shall be rendered in .docx format. Reading around SO, I found that it is possible to provide some pandoc arguments among which `toc-title` could address my issue. Nevertheless I was not able to do it. My current YAML header is:

```
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: stile_tesi.docx
    toc: yes
    fig_caption: true
    #pandoc_args: [
    # "--toc-title", "INDICE"
    #]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  word_document: 
    toc: yes
toc-title: "INDICE"
---
```

Important: Watch out the correct indention!